# C#: run command with elevated permissions and capture output

Tags: c#, process, elevated-privileges, elevation, privilege-elevation

I'd like to run a command with elevated permissions while capturing the output:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo("FSUTIL", "dirty query c:");
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";

            var proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            System.Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `startInfo.Verb = "runas";` requires `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`, which is not compatible `RedirectStandardOutpu`.

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to your request, but will show you some problems on your approach and a way to avoid all.

If your program doesn't runs as elevated, each time you call the external program it will request elevated privileges to the user, so at some point the user will be requested to elevate privileges to a program.

Said so, you can run your program with elevated privileges, in this way when you launch the external program it will inherit the elevated privileges.

To do your program to request elevated privileges on run read [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Comment: When I set <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />, the app opens in a separate console. So I am still unable to catch stdout. I would like to _steal_ the output from the elevated console and copy it on the in the originating console.

Comment: Remove the "runas" verb and ensure you set UseShellExecute to false.

Comment: Done to no avail. I think it is normal for elevated console apps to open in a distinct console. The point is to capture the output in the new elevated console and sending it on the original one.